# Inheritance and Generics Java problem Observer

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

I'm experiencing a problem, I don't know if this overloading is correct.
I'm applying this on many cases, for instance:

```
public class Subject<T>{
  private  long id;
    private T data;
   protected List<Observer<T>> observers;  <code>
//..
    public List<Observer<T>> getObservers() {
        return observers;
    }
//..
}

public class OrdersSubject  extends Subject<List<Order>>{

    String status;
    List<List<Order>> reentrantOrders;
    boolean islimit = false;
    Long limit = 0l;
    //..
    public  List<RobotObserver> getObservers(){
        return this.observers;
    }
   //..

}
```

Will I get correct getObservers() ,
thanks in anticipation.

```
In fact this is the implementation of RobotObserver:

public class RobotObserver extends Observer<List<Order>> implements RobotCallback{

Map<Integer,String> sysstat = new HashMap<Integer,String>();
private Subject subject;
//eActLevel is a Map containing and ordered list of <emotion,transitions of emotion list>
private Map<String,List<Double>> eActLevel;
//..
public List<Order> update(List<Order> o) {
    // reentrant Orders
    reentrantO = processOrders(o);
    this.data = this.callback(reentrantO);
    return data;
}
```

}

```
import java.util.List;

     import com.res.emorobots.data.Order;

      interface RobotCallback extends Callback<List<Order>>{


       }
```

And I get a compilation error. I'm comming from c++ world, in fact I would be interested in change List by what is called in c++ deque and implementing vector interface

In fact I'm looking for something like this:

```
public class RobotObserver extends Observer<K<Order> implements List<Order>> implements Callback...
```

Comment: I solved this question with this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9893481/generics-inheriting-from-an-abstract-class-that-implements-an-interface

Answer (score 0):

`OrdersSubject::getObservers()` does not correctly override `Subject::getObservers()`. `OrdersSubject` extends `Subject<List<Order>>`, and so its `getObservers()` method should return `List<Observer<List<Order>>>`. But it does not. It instead returns `List<RobotObserver>`.

`List<RobotObserver>` is not a subtype of `List<Observer<List<Order>>>`, even though `RobotObserver` is a subtype of `Observer<List<Order>>`, just like how `List<String>` is not a subtype of `List<Object>` even though `String` is a subtype of `Object`. Non-wildcard generic type arguments must match exactly.